# Magento 2 composer issue with bitbucket pipelines

Tags: magento2, composer

I made a bitbucket pipeline and I would like to do some deployments, but my pipeline got stuck with a composer issue.
This is the error message from the pipeline:

```
The 'https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/framework/magento-framework-102.0.4.0.zip' URL required authentication.                                
You must be using the interactive console to authenticate
```

If I access that link, I got this:

```
You haven't provided your Magento authentication keys. For instructions, visit 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html
```

But the thing is that I have my keys added in the `auth.json` and if do a `composer install` or `update`, it works, so I m not sure why it doesn't work from the pipeline and what exactly that error means. Can you please clarify it ? or give me some advice?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe this will give you some idea, it's from Magento cloud but can fit:. https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/integrations/bitbucket-integration.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I leave this answer, maybe it will help someone:
I used a docker image from [Hipex](https://hub.docker.com/r/hipex/deploy/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated) and I needed to add a variable called: `DEPLOY_COMPOSER_AUTH` from `Repository settings`. It's value needed to be the output of `cat auth.json | base64`

Comment: I also have this issue. The thing is that I successfully executed ~100 pipeline jobs and at some point it stopped working and I got the same error. I have configured different M2 public and private keys but still no luck. Is there a limitation maybe on how many M2 installs you can do in a period of time?

Answer (score 0):

Pipeline running on the virtual machine provided by the bitbucket. So in general that auth.json needs to be under the current machine user .composer/auth.json
So, you need to make sure before composer install running in the pipeline you must specify or create auth.json to the virtual machine. This will resolve the problem.

Comment: can you share an example or article with more details with this ? thank you